# Scrapy - Filtered duplicate request

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm working with scrapy. I want to loop through a db table and grab the starting page for each scrape (random_form_page), then yield a request for each start page. Please note that I am hitting an api to get a proxy with the initial request. I want to set up each request to have its own proxy, so using the callback model I have:

```
def start_requests(self):
    for x in xrange(8): 
        random_form_page = session.query(....

        PR = Request(
            'htp://my-api',
            headers=self.headers,
            meta={'newrequest': Request(random_form_page,  headers=self.headers)},
            callback=self.parse_PR
        )
        yield PR
```

I notice:

```
[scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET 'htp://my-api'> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
```

In my code I can see that although it loops through 8 times it only yields a request for the first page. The others I assume are being filtered out. I've looked at http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#dupefilter-class but still unsure how to turn off this filtering action. How can I turn off the filtering?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

use

> dont_filter = True in Request object

```
def start_requests(self):
    for x in xrange(8): 
        random_form_page = session.query(....

        PR = Request(
            'htp://my-api',
            headers=self.headers,
            meta={'newrequest': Request(random_form_page,  headers=self.headers)},
            callback=self.parse_PR,
            dont_filter = True
        )
        yield PR
```

Answer (score 12):

As/if you are accessing an API you most probably want to disable the duplicate filter altogether:

```
# settings.py
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter'
```

This way you don't have to clutter all your Request creation code with `dont_filter=True`.

One word of caution, though (thanks to Brick Yang's comment): if your spider is crawling a website by discovering, extracting and following links you should not do this, as your spider is likely picking up the same links multiple times and would be recrawling them over and over again - resulting in an endless crawling loop.

Comment: Thx! This worked. Although `dont_filter=True` may be a better idea. According to https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#dupefilter-class

Comment: Thanks, added a warning

Comment: also for `yield from response.follow_all(items, self.parse_detail, dont_filter=True)`